# If-Else statement is flip-flopped

Tags: objective-c, ios, if-statement

I am creating an application in iOS SDK and the user must enter a password to access their content. I am using an If-Else statement to verify their password. Problem is, the If-else statement is working backwards, not like it should. For example: If The user enters the correct password then the label text says: Wrong Password. If the user enters the wrong password then the label text says: Password is Correct. That is the exact opposite of what I want it to do. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)isKeywordSecure:(id)sender {
    NSString *Key = [Keyword text];
    if ([Key compare:@"Password"]) {
        SecurityLevel.text=@"Keyword is Correct";
    } else {
        SecurityLevel.text=@"Keyword is WRONG";
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NSString `compare:` method, like nearly all string comparison routines, returns zero if the strings compare equal (to be precise, it returns `NSOrderedSame`, which is zero).

You can replace your if condition with

```
if ([Key compare:@"Password"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    SecurityLevel.text=@"Keyword is Correct";
```

or use the `isEqualToString:` method instead.

All of this is in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare%3aoptions%3arange%3alocale%3a), with which you should familiarize yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the documentation for [`-[NSString compare:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-compare_); it doesn't return a boolean, but rather a [`NSComparisonResult`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW9).  The value it returns is zero if the two strings are equal, which is equivalent to `NO`.  You should use `isEqualToString:` instead.